# Is there a way to count the number of iterations using contiperf rule

Tags: java, iteration, performance-testing, contiperf

I need to know the number of iterations made in the entire period of my performance test.

I currently use contiperf rule. how can I get the number of iterations made using the same? If not any other better way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to check own code, you can use this resource:
https://gist.github.com/adamrduffy/79beff80adc9f022bb7f.
In generally, I didn't a better approach.

Comment: that would make me tell the app "do 100 invocations in an hour". Isnt there a way to find how many is made by default?

Comment: The default is 1 as you can see in the code https://github.com/javatlacati/contiperf/blob/43b7660fbe039e0760beea51453120008644727d/src/main/java/com/github/javatlacati/contiperf/PerfTest.java#L99

Comment: @RuslanLópez  Thanks!